# Form rendering incorrectly

Tags: html, css

I am submitting an HTML form to a PHP script which works well, what does not work well is when the PHP runs, the LOGO I have covers the returned user text from the form and I cannot seem to move the form information down, when I modify CSS to affect the returned user input, nothing happens. The logo is fine on the form html page but How do I move the user input down to be below the logo instead of stuck behind it on the returned PHP page?

HTML:

```
 <div id="logo">
    <img src=http://mylogo.com/logojpg>
</div>
<div id="user">
    <form action="Form.php" method="post" id="myform" name="myform">
    <p class="topofdiv">Please sign up</p>
    <p>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" size="30">
    </p>

    <p>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" size="30">
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="adduser" value="Submit Information">
    </p>

    </form>
```

CSS:

```
    html {margin:0; padding:0;}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: blue;
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

input {
    font-size: 20px;
}

select {
    font-size: 55px;
}

#user{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 550px;
    padding: 10px;

}

#logo
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}

#myform{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
```

PHP:

```
 $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

print("<div ><strong>Thanks for your Input</strong></div>");
print("<div><br><br>Welcome to the site " . $firstname . " " . $lastname . "</div>");
?>
```

Comment: Where are you closing the #logo div?

Comment: not really PHP problem it's more html & css. But you haven't close your div tag : 

<div id="logo">
<img src=http://mylogo.com/logojpg> try to close it : 

<div id="logo">
<img src=http://mylogo.com/logojpg></div>

Comment: Wow I am going to delete this post, the closing of the logo div solved my issue *stupid me.

Comment: @Inaso, I know it's more CSS I just didn't want to leave anything out of the equation. But you are right!

Comment: Another thing worth to mention: please use double quotes when using attributes within HTML: `<img src=http://mylogo.com/logojpg>` should be `<img src="http://mylogo.com/logojpg">`

Comment: KarelG, I changed this too, thank you.

Comment: Dont’t close it, someone else might find it useful. Thanks